# How to transfer information from android to servlet?

Tags: java, android, servlets

i would like to send some information from within my application to a servlet that will then jsut display the information to the console window(running server through eclipse).

Firstly how do i send the information(a simple string) to servlet?

Secondly what do i call in the servlet for it to print to the console?

Also should i for the first step set up a Service to run the sending of information in the background?

Answer (score 0):

- WebServices
- HttpURLConnection

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer from @Jigar is complete, a more general way to say it is that you can pass a parameter to a http request made from your android app to the server. It can be with post or get, get is simpler.

Regards,
Stéphane